# Como criar arquivo no meu PC, dentro de uma rede interna, usando PHP

Tags: php, arquivo, path, fopen

Estou desenvolvendo um software para a empresa que trabalho e me surgiu um problema: eu preciso criar um arquivo dentro do meu PC que seja salvo usando qualquer outro computador da rede interna da empresa.
Antes eu tinha feito ele para funcionar na minha máquina. Então usava a função fopen() para criar o arquivo e usava o caminho "/srv/http/programa/" para poder salvar. 
Agora que eu pretendo colocar ele na rede interna da empresa eu queria saber como salvar o arquivo na mesma pasta, dentro do meu computador, mas usando um outro pc na rede. 
Eu já tentei usar o ip da minha máquina e o resto do caminho, mas não funciona. Dá erro 404 - Objeto não encontrado.

Comment: Onde a aplicação PHP será executada? Em cada uma das máquinas isoladamente?

Comment: Isso. Em máquinas isoladas.

Comment: Pergunta: Por quê? Não é melhor deixar sua aplicação rodando na sua máquina e outros usuários apenas acessá-la remotamente?

Comment: Poderia ser. Como seria a melhor forma de implementar?

Comment: Esta. Como está rodando a aplicação? Apache?

Comment: Isso. Estou usando o apache em um Manjaro Linux. Mas tenho a opção de fazer também em um host na web, mas prefiro usar meu computador como servidor.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55140/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-rafael-pessoa).